# I have a list of 1000 words, I need to make sure that each word is written on a separate picture. how can i automate this?

Tags: list, photo

I attached photo example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3hvY.jpg

I need to do the same with 1000 words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate with python using the PILL library.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw ,ImageFont
 
words = ['Hello World' , 'Good Morning' , 'Coffee']

for number,word in enumerate(words):
    img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), color =(0,0,0)) #(0,0,0) means black
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf",50)
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    d.text((400,400), word , font = font,fill=(255,255,255)) #(255,255,255) is white
    img.save(f'pil_text{number}.jpg')
```

In the above code, you can change the background color, font size, font type, name of file. You can add your word list in 'word' manually or load a file in python. The code will slightly change then depending whats the file you are loading.